# recover private keys (RSA)generated with weak LCG

Tags: rsa, random-number-generator

How is it possible to recover RSA private keys considering that weak LCG (random number generator) is used?
I have some other keys (Public and private created with the same generator) and also some crypt texts encrypted with both keys.

It is relevant to highlight that there is no clue about the algorithm used to create those keys.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Private keys may help to confirm or find what LCG that is, or/and how it is seeded. Then enumerating the private keys this LCG and plausible seeds is able to generate may help find which private key matches a given public key.

Comment: Is there any script / python program or sage small script which can be used for that purpose?